# Вопрос по Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Не удалось найти ответ на следующий вопрос: создается какой-то JFrame внутри которого несколько панелей, создается ActionListener:

```
public class PushingListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Начать бой")){
            Graphics.setButton("Продолжить бой", false);
            battleTank();
        }
    }
}
```

Кнопка и все поля обновляются только после того как функция battleTank полностью отработает. Можно ли как-то принудительно заставлять обновляться изменившиеся поля после каждого тика внутри программы battleTank()?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте обновлять своё окно по таймеру:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
 @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    frame.repaint; 
     }
});
```

Comment: Я вот вспомнил, что repaint() - это асинхронный процесс. Т.е. фактически перерисовка случится не известно когда. Нужен способ немедленной перересовки.

Comment: Вот repaint и не работает, update еще есть, но я не понимаю как его вживить в программу

Answer (score 0):

Находясь в потоке диспетчера событий (EDT), вызывайте метод `paintImmediately(...)`
Аргумент - прямоугольник внутри компонента, который нужно нарисовать, в виде координат или Rectangle (надо как-то получить этот прямоугольник)

```
component.paintImmediately(component.getBounds(null));
```

Вне EDT используйте `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable doRun)` для синхронного выполнения кода в EDT. Например

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
    component.paintImmediately(component.getBounds(null)); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась нетривиально...после каждого тика battleTank() кидает команду на соответствующие панели centerPanel.update(centerPanel.getGraphics()).

component.paintImmediately(component.getBounds(null)) - не работает корректно, так как он берет размер прямоугольника, но не учитывает, что он находится не в точке 0.0 и потому обновляет только кусок она в точке 0.0 + размеры прямоугольника и в итоге все плохо)